# Full Calendar Event for Every Sunday

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar and pulling events from a database. I would like to add a standard event for every Sunday to include on the event calendar without having to add an entry in the database for every Sunday of the year.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FullCalendar has support for recurring events, and it is [clearly explained in the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events).  You simply define an event with one or more extra properties specifying the details.  If you just want to repeat on Sunday, use `daysOfWeek: [0]`, where `0` represents Sunday.

If you want this in *addition* to an existing JSON feed of events, you can use [the `eventSources` property](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources), which allows you to specify multiple sources of events.  So something like this specifies both your JSON feed as well as the set of recurring Sunday events:

```js
eventSources: [
    '/my/json/events',
    [{
        title: 'Recurring!',
        start: '2022-01-01',
        end: '2023-01-01',
        daysOfWeek: [0],
    }]
]
```

Working snippet, of recurring events, without JSON feed:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Recurring!',
                start: '2022-01-01',
                end: '2023-01-01',
                daysOfWeek: [0],
            }
        ]
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.3/main.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.3/main.min.css">

<div id="calendar"></div>
```